# Kali tools on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux

Okay, So I am new to UBUNTU, and have little experience with Kali and Backtrack! so I wanted to install **ALL** the Kali Linux tools in UBUNTU, not one by one, or just transform the Kali Linux into Ubuntu does anyone have the answer, I couldn't find any related questions asked before :\

### if u don't know about all the tools, so no problem But I need these tools :D :

> 1. AirCrack
> 2. Burp Suite
> 3. Hydra
> 4. John the Ripper
> 5. Maltego
> 6. Metasploit Framework
> 7. Armitage
> 8. Zed Attack Proxy
> 9. Sqlmap
> 10. Wireshark
> 11. address6
> 12. Deblaze
> 13. Tnscmd10g
> 14. BBQSQL
> 15. Blueranger
> 16. Lynis
> 17. DotDotPwn
> 18. Netgear-telnetable
> 19. Terminator
> 20. Htexploit
> 21. Jboss-autopwn
> 22. Websploit
> 23. Bluepot
> 24. Spooftooph
> 25. Smartphone-Pentest-Framework
> 26. Fern-Wifi-cracker
> 27. Wi-fihoney
> 28. Wifite
> 29. Creddump
> 30. Johnny
> 31. Manglefizz
> 32. Ophcrack
> 33. Phrasendresher
> 34. Rainbowcrack
>
> 35.Acccheck
>
> 36.Smbexec

Comment: Okay, so can anyone tell me why is it rated negatively??

Comment: Why can't you simply install them all using apt-get? You seem to know all the names, so where's the problem?

Comment: "How to install Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu with this easy script" - http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-kali-linux-tools-on-ubuntu-with-this-easy-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just install [Kali](http://www.kali.org/)?  Some of these tools are kind of a hassle to set up (especially Metasploit), that's why Kali was created.

If you don't want to give up your current Ubuntu install, you can create a virtual machine using tools like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: If you find this an acceptable answer to your question, please flag it as an Accepted Answer.